# Copy wpf imageSource to another wpf imageSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to copy imageSource to another imageSource. When A window contains image is closed, then I want to make image in A will be copied to B window image and then open B window.

I tried to test with below code. but it wasn`t work.

ADDED : 
I upload more code about relevant image code. but i`m sorry that i can`t upload full source code but If you ask, I will edit the related source and upload it.

```
   A a = new A();
   B b;
   a.Closing += delegate {
                    b = new B();
                    b.img.Source = a.img.Source;
                    b.Show();
   };
   a.Show();
```

```xml
<!-- a.img xml -->
<Grid x:Name="ImageGrid" Margin="0,36,10,10">
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTransform"
                                        ScaleX="{Binding ZoomRate}" ScaleY="{Binding ZoomRate}"/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <Image Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Source="{Binding BitmapSource, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Name="canvas2"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=imgBefore2}"
                        Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=imgBefore2}"

                        MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas2_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                        MouseMove="Canvas2_MouseMove"
                        MouseLeftButtonUp="Canvas2_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                        MouseRightButtonDown="Canvas2_MouseRightButtonDown">
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>

<!-- b.img xml -->
<Grid x:Name="ImageGrid"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Width="{Binding MaxWidth, ElementName=ScrollViewer}"
                        Height="{Binding MaxHeight, ElementName=ScrollViewer}"
                        MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"
                        MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                        MouseLeftButtonUp="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                        MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel">
                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTransform" ScaleX="{Binding ZoomRate}" ScaleY="{Binding ZoomRate}"/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    <Image x:Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            x:Name="canvas"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=imgBefore}"
                            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=imgBefore}"/>
                </Grid>
```

```
public Mat src;
public BitmapSource BitmapSource {
            get
            {   
                return bitmapSource;
            }
            set
            {
                bitmapSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("bitmapSource");
            } // ViewModel Code
}

private void LoadImage(System.Drawing.Bitmap bm)
{
  src = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(bm);
  OriginWidth = src.Width;
  OriginHeight = src.Height;
  BitmapSource = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapSourceConverter.ToBitmapSource(src);
} // Load Image for a.img
```

Comment: @Clemens When a.img.Source is bound on b.img.Source, it does not show any error, but image is not showed on b.img. a.img and b.img are Image class

Comment: how are you setting a.img.Source?

Comment: @Raka <Image Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Source="{Binding BitmapSource}"/> It is just all

Comment: @Raka private void LoadImage(System.Drawing.Bitmap bm)
        {
             src = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(bm);
            OriginWidth = src.Width;
            OriginHeight = src.Height;
            BitmapSource = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapSourceConverter.ToBitmapSource(src);
        }

Comment: @JYLee If you want to add relevant code parts, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56555037/edit). Code in comments is unreadable. Right now, your question can't be answered, since `b.img.Source = a.img.Source;` would just work.

Comment: There is `OnPropertyChanged("bitmapSource")`, which should be `OnPropertyChanged("BitmapSource")` or better `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BitmapSource))`. However, that does not explain why `b.img.Source = a.img.Source` won't work.